# sorting lists highest to lowest and defining variables

Tags: python, list, sorting

This is my code, how do I update the name_scores at the end so that I can call upon it later (using global) with it being ordered.

```
with open(class_number, "r") as file: #1
    file.seek(0) #2
    scores = file.readlines() #3
    name_scores = { } #4
    for line in scores: #5
        name, score = line.rstrip('\n').split(':') #6
        score = int(score) #7
        if name not in name_scores: #8
            name_scores[name] = []   #9    # Initialize score list
        name_scores[name].append(score) #10  # Add the most recent score
        if len(name_scores[name]) > 3:   #11
            name_scores[name].pop(0)   #12
```

When I try and `print(name_scores)`outside the function 
I get:

```
NameError: name 'name_scores' is not defined
```

But I don't know if it is "name_scores" I want to print

I'm trying to order the last three scores highest to lowest, in alphabetical order

```
with open(view_class, "r") as file: #1
    for name in sorted(name_scores): #16
        name_scores = (sort(name_scores, reverse = True))
        print(name, '-', name_scores[name])
```

Comment: Is it `class_scores` or `name_scores`?

Comment: Where is the `print` statement?

Comment: @PeterWood name_scores, I have not used class_scores anywhere why?

Comment: You say: *I try and print("class_scores)*

Comment: sorry, let me append one second

Comment: @PeterWood ok i have appended, it is name_scores

Comment: Your problem doesn't appear to be related to the code you have posted. If this code is in a function, and you're trying to access the data outside that function, you need to return it.

Comment: ok, @DanielRoseman how do i return it?

Comment: @M.Weiss That's a basic python question. Have you read [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/)? For example the section [Defining Functions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

Comment: The question still mentions `class_scores`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman ahh sorry yes ofc I have returned it, it is running but says that name_scores hasn't been defined